# Hadoop - java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer when creating when creating a new directory

Tags: java, hadoop, fedora-18

I have installed hadoop 2.4.0 as a single node for learning purposes but after I start hadoop and create a directory using the command:

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /tmp
```

I get the following error:

```
ls: Failed on local exception: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer; Host Details : local host is: "localhost.localdomain/127.0.0.1"; destination host is: "localhost":9000;
```

I'm really a bigginner to hadoop and I Searched about this error but could not catch anything.